# Не могу опубликовать приложение через dotnet publish. На одном сервере нормально, на другом выдает ошибку

Tags: windows, .net, asp.net-core

Не могу опубликовать приложение через dotnet publish.
На одном сервере нормально,на другом выдает ошибку

```
Failed to compile.
  
  Warning
  (3786:3) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.
  
  
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\9hzz-ST3\0\root\gitlab-ci-iis\Project1\Project1.csproj(36,5): error MSB3073: The command "npm run build" exited with code 1.
```

В логах еще такие предупреждения

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/schemas@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'diff-sequences@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-diff@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-get-type@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/console@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/test-result@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/types@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-message-util@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-regex-util@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-util@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'jest-watcher@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'pretty-format@28.0.2',
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=17.0.0' },
  npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.4.2', npm: '7.18.1' }
  npm WARN EBADENGINE }
  npm WARN deprecated @types/reactstrap@8.7.2: This is a stub types definition. reactstrap provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
  npm WARN deprecated @types/jest-diff@24.3.0: This is a stub types definition. jest-diff provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
  npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
  npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
```

dotnet build проходит нормально.

Куда еще можно копать?

Необходимые версии NetCore одинаковые поставил (3.1.25)

- 1 сервер (все окей)

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

- 2 сервер (с ошибкой)

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.419 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.310 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.25 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется вы одни предупреждения в логах показали. Где-то должна быть и ошибка, поищите по слову `error` или `fail`.

Comment: Все заработало. Но только при запуске через командную строку. Но не работает через Gitlab ci. До этого через командную строку не пробовал, а жаль, столько времени потерял (
Сейчас разбираюсь

Comment: Выяснил что npm возвращает код ошибки 1 из за варнирнингов
И из за этого пайплайн падал в ошибку, пришлось исправлять кастылем
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917977/disable-npm-warnings-as-errors-build-definition-tfs)